# How to accept all changesets with no code changes in RTC?

Tags: version-control, changeset, rational-team-concert

I have a project in IBM ALM which uses several external components. Every time the team developing those components makes a release, they create a snapshot with [baselines for all components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o57D.png). As a result, when I want to update my project to the latest release, I see incoming changesets on all components, most of which consist of only the baseline labels with the snapshot name, with no actual code changes.

Is there a way to automatically accept all such "empty" changesets, so that I can clearly see the remaining components which have *actual* changes and have a chance to analyse those changes before accepting them?

Answer (score 1):

That was asked 4 years ago in [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/174039/hide-baseline-from-pending-changes-view), and referred to [RTC Work Item 189873](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=189873), which was rejected.

[This thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/195623/how-to-ignore-incoming-change-in-rtc-pending-changes-view) proposed:

> As far as I known there's no way to hide incoming change sets.
>
> But you can hide empty baseline created by other users from Eclipse Preference, select `Team > Jazz Source Control > Changes`.
> In the right panel, **uncheck "`Show all baselines (including empty baseline and baselines created by others)`"**.

Comment: Thanks, what you found looks relevant. Unfortunately, unchecking the option doesn't have the desired effect and apparently I'm [not](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/174039/hide-baseline-from-pending-changes-view) [alone](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/68064/empty-baseline-in-incomingoutgoing-queue/68066) in being unable to get it to work.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev That is what I thought... unfortunately, any related RFE is  often quite slow to be implemented.